# Retrieve Cluster Inactivity Time on Azure Databricks Notebook

Tags: azure, cluster-computing, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-notebooks

I'm new to Azure Databricks and I'm using it for a project.

As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/clusters-manage) in the documentation for `Automatic termination` it says

*You can also set auto termination for a cluster.
During cluster creation, you can specify an `inactivity period` in minutes after which you want the cluster to terminate.
If the difference between the `current time` and the `last command` run on the cluster is more than the inactivity period specified,
Azure Databricks automatically terminates that cluster.*

Is there a workaround to get the real time inactivity period (the difference between the current time and the last command run on the cluster) of a cluster on the Azure Databricks Notebooks via the [Cluster API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters) or any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# Function to retrieve cluster inactivity time
from datetime import datetime
import time

def cluster_inactivity_time(log_file_path):
 
  # Open log4j-active.log and read last line
  with open(log_file_path, "r") as file:
    first_line = file.readline()
    for last_line in file:
        pass
      
  # Convert last lines' timestamp to milliseconds
  last_run_time = last_line[9:17]
  current_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  last_run_datetime = round(datetime.strptime(current_date + ' ' + last_run_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp() * 1000)
  
  # Finding the difference between current time and last command run time
  current_time = round(time.time() * 1000)
  difference = current_time - last_run_datetime
  inactivity_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(difference / 1000.0)
  print(f'The Cluster has been Inactive for {inactivity_time.hour}:{inactivity_time.minute}:{inactivity_time.second}')


# Function Call
log_file_path = '/dbfs/cluster-logs/0809-101642-leap143/driver/log4j-active.log'
cluster_inactivity_time(log_file_path)
```

Output:

The Cluster has been Inactive for 0:0:35

Comment: this does not work, even we are not running any command for the cluster. The logs still updated pretty frequently.

Comment: @jdhao Care to elaborate on your issue?

Comment: I mean even if the cluster is inactive, the log file is still updated. You cann't extract timestamp from last time and subtract it with current time to get the inactivity.

Comment: @jdhao The answer has most likely deprecated with improvements in Databricks. I now believe that using a combination of different Databricks API endpoints this can be achieved .